# Ajuda com Join em Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, select

Encontrei no site diversas perguntas/respostas sobre join, porém ainda não consegui criar o comando que necessito. O que preciso é o seguinte:

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

item (tenho dois itens cadastrados)

```
id
descricao
---------------
1 - dipirona
2 - paracetamol
```

itemdetalhe (desses itens, tenho apenas dipirona de duas marcas diferentes)

```
id
item
marca
-------------------
1 - 1 - medley
2 - 1 - medlab
```

itematual (no estoque, tenho 1000 dipironas de uma marca e 1500 de outra)

```
id
itemdetalhe
qtd
----------------
1 - 1 - 1000
2 - 2 - 1500
```

O que preciso é gerar algo assim:

```
item.id | itemdetalhe.id | item.descricao | itemdetalhe.marca | itematual.qtd
1         1                dipirona         medley              1000
1         2                dipirona         medlab              1500
2                          paracetamol
```

Comment: dá uma olhada no site que tem várias perguntas com respostas sobre `join` no `mysql`

Comment: @RicardoPontual já vi algumas respostas sim, inclusive de perguntas minhas, porem, nao estao me ajudando nesse caso específico

Comment: mas explique melhor, qual a dificuldade então?

Comment: @RicardoPontual a dificuldade é que nao consegui fazer o que necessito na pergunta. dá uma lida

Comment: mas onde está seu `sql`? pra mim continua vago

Comment: O que você quer é o `left join`. Assim você pode buscar os dados com uma tabela base ignorando a falta deles em outra tabela

Comment: isso mesmo @Sorack, testei aqui e resolveu. se for possível escrever a resposta, fique a vontade pra ganhar seus pontos. abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso você precisa fazer um `JOIN` que traga as informações da tabela base mesmo que não existam dados nas tabelas de referência. [Nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/59479) você pode conferir as diferenças entre os `JOINS`. Aplicando na sua necessidade:

```
SELECT i.id AS 'item_id',
      id.id AS 'item_detalhe_id',
      i.descricao,
      id.marca,
      ia.qtd
  FROM item i
      LEFT JOIN itemdetalhe id ON id.item = i.id
      LEFT JOIN itematual ia ON ia.itemdetalhe = id.id
```

Onde os dados de item aparecerão mesmo que não existam dados nas tabelas `itemdetalhe` e `itematual`.